# Semi-colon in an field used as a lookup causes Error:Value does not fall within the expected range

Tags: lookup-column, modern

In SharePoint Online, on a modern site, create a list with 2 values.  For the first value, use no special characters.  For the second value, include a semi-colon.
ListOne
ItemOne
Item;Two

Create a second list.  Add a lookup column:
Get Information from: ListOne
In this column: Title
Allow multiple values: checked

In the second list, create a new item
Title:  Test
Lookup:

The page will display: Error:Value does not fall within the expected range.

Is this a bug or undocumented feature?  Are semi-colons allowed in Lookup columns?

This error is displayed in a modern list.  If I switch to classic view.  I can add the item and an error is not displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Sharepoint, a semicolon is used as data in a checkbox-enabled Choice column which acts as a separator/delimiter between two values. Using SemiColon(;) in text causes data and search problems. Don't put semicolons in multi-choice (Checkbox) columns